Is there a way to send data between Windows processes and authenticate the user?
I am looking to have a secure communications channel, such as a socket, between two processes on the same Windows based machine.  In particular, I am looking to have the operating system authenticate that the sender is the same user as the receiver (the receiver relies on the OS for the authentication).  I am targeting "same user" meaning they have the same SID, although I am open to answers which define "same user" differently.
On Linux, this functionality can be accomplished via Unix Sockets using SO_PEERCRED.  I am looking for similar on Windows, although it does not need to be handled via sockets if Windows has a preferred non-socket way of authenticating.

Named pipes, for example, are securable objects. You can provide a security descriptor when you create the pipe, and then Windows will make sure only allowed users can access the pipe.
